# filter[0].ID is undefined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I am making a Discord Bot add a database entry when a new user joins. To avoid duplicate entries I'm checking if the database row ID already has the members ID in it. My problem is if the member is not in the database it comes back as undefined.

```
var userID = member.id.toString();
var UserName = member.user.username.toString();
// var NickName = member.nickname.toString();
var DateJoined = new Date();
    con.query("SELECT ID FROM listAllUsers", function (err, selectResult, fields) {
        var filter = selectResult.filter(m => m.ID === userID);
        console.log(filter[0].ID)
        if(filter[0].ID == userID) {
            console.log(`That user all ready exists in the database.`)
        } else {
            var sql = `INSERT INTO listAllUsers (ID, UserName, NickName, DateJoined) VALUES ('${ID}', '${UserName}', 'none', '${DateJoined}')`;
            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(`User: ${UserName} -- ${ID} has joined the server. Added to the Database`);
            });
        }
    });
```

`var filter = selectResult.filter(m => m.ID === userID);`
This checks if the ID is equal to any of the ID's in the database. But this is also my problem. Because if this comes back empty it will make this:
`console.log(filter[0].ID)` undefined. Well actually the .ID bit comes back undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have an entry, than you already know the id exists....

```
if (filter.length > 0) { 
  // you have a user with the id
}
```

But wouldn't it make more sense to just query the user id instead of returning everyone? `SELECT ID FROM listAllUsers WHERE ID=userID`